# How could randomly my session is null?

Tags: tomcat, jsf

I am using Tomcat 6.0, JSF2.0.2

I realized that randomly `HttpServletRequest getSession` method, returns null.

I could the session randomly be null?

How can I debug who sets the session to null?

I checked it with `request.getSession(true)` and it returns null. How could it be that it cannot create a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this problem is not related to JSF since it's "just" a component based MVC framework. This problem is more related to the servletcontainer in question, which is in this case thus Tomcat.

As to the problem: I've seen this before in specific portal(-like) applications. Tomcat has some builtin phishing prevention which would return a `null` session when the given cookie ID and path doesn't match with any cookie in Tomcat's session manager. More than often this problem can be solved by setting `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) `<Connector>` in `conf/server.xml` to `true`.

Comment: I tried it - but it doesn't help.

I still get from time to time this error message:(

Comment: Debug the request headers to check if the valid cookie is there. If not, then it's a client or proxy issue

Comment: What we had to do was to set the user_id that both on externalcontext session and tomcat request session like this:
ExternalContext ectx =    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ectx.getRequest();
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ectx.getSession( false );
  ectx.getSessionMap().put( Constants.CURRENT_USER_ID_ATTR, user.getId() );
  session.setAttribute( Constants.CURRENT_USER_ID_ATTR, user.getId() );
  req.getSession( false ).setAttribute( Constants.CURRENT_USER_ID_ATTR, user.getId() );

interesting, ha?