# HttpServletRequest.getSession(false): When does it return null?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'd like to know when to expect a "null" when calling [HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

Also: Are there good tutorials on HttpSession? I'd like to get details like: when to invalidate()? what are the consequences? do I need to check if the returned HttpSession is valid? ... <== Answer that in a comment please.

Comment: I did exactly that for a site of mine when I realized that there were certain search engines that did not honor my robots.txt. In short, you call getSession(boolean) with false as a parameter. This returns the session if there is one, or null, if there is none. Then you call .getAttributeNames() on the session, which on an invalidated session (timed out, closed) throws an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should practically never expect a null value. As the documentation says, if there is no active session for a request (usually, you would check for that in the filter chain of a request), a session will be created. If you get a null value from this, I'd wager that there is a problem in the underlying OS: Not enough memory to spawn a session would come to mind.

Comment: Here's the example that brought me to ask this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080203/how-could-randomly-my-session-is-null. I'm wondering whether there are more cases like this. Do others agree that having a filter check for a session is a good idea?

Comment: As the poster said, he tried getSession(true), which according to my experience and the documentation will create the session, if it doesn't already exists. If it is not created, I'd wager that this is a problem with finite resources or some other problem (as one poster suggested, maybe an anti-phishing tech), but I'm not familiar with any in the mentioned application server (tomcat).

Comment: ok so under normal circumstances (your pplication is running with enough resources, ...), you shouldn't get null. Good enough (I'll leave this open for a day so that other can comment if needed).

Comment: I totally misread the API, so I changed my question so that it uses getSession(false). Does this change your answer? You're not forcing the creation of a session, but should you still have 1??

Comment: Yes, that changes the answer. For example, inside the filter chain, if this request comes from a client who has previously called this website and has the capabilities to accept a session (either via cookie or jsessionid) and resupplies the information back to the application server, then there is a session already open for the request, and the call should return the session object. However, if this is the first request or the caller doesn't give back the necessary information to determine that this is a follow-up request, then the call returns null.

Comment: That's rather strange. I have added a WebListener (HttpSessionListener), and simply visiting the index page (a simple hello world JSP) fires a sessionCreated() event. A session is created, so why could it return null later on in my code? Thank you for you time ;)

Comment: This can very well be. After some idle time (without a new request), the session will be invalidated anyway (it's usually a configuration issue after what idle time this occurs). Another way a session can be invalidated prematurely is by calling session.invalidate() manually. There might be a number of ways to automagically invalidate sessions due to actions (think of intrusion detection/prevention systems), for which you could check your application server installation. Even some caching mechanisms can invalidate sessions to force a re-caching for content after certain timeouts.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE Can you please update the answer to reflect the change to the question (that it's now asking about `getSession(false)`, not `getSession(true)`)?  I was tempted to downvote the blatant "misunderstanding" of the documentation until I read the comments and saw that the question was changed after you first posted and that you do indeed answer the new question correctly in the comments.